# Parse SQL parameter marker with pandas using dynamic tables

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I have the following code:

```
query = """
    DECLARE @DATABASE VARCHAR(128) = '{}';
    DECLARE @SCHEMA VARCHAR(128) = '{}';
    DECLARE @TABLE VARCHAR(128) = '{}';
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(200) = 
    'SELECT * FROM ' + CONCAT(QUOTENAME(@DATABASE), '.', QUOTENAME(@SCHEMA), '.', QUOTENAME(@TABLE), ' WHERE COD = ?')
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    """.format(
    db_config.db.database, db_config.db.schema, db_config.db.table
)

return pd.read_sql_query(
    query, db_config.db.connection, params=[cod_sol]
)
```

It was working right until I added a sql param marker `' WHERE COD = ?'`. It seems pandas or pyodbc can't parse that type of query, with a simple sql statement it works, but not with dynamic tables.

Here is the result of the final `@sql` variable:

```
SELECT * FROM [DB].[SCHEMA].[TABLE] WHERE COD = ?
```

So it seems to be right.

It's possible to do that sort of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to solve it!

Instead of trying to execute directly the sql statement in one step, I first construct the sql query, and generate its final form:

```
SELECT * FROM [DB].[SCHEMA].[TABLE] WHERE COD = ?
```

Then, I call `read_sql_query` passing in the params

```
query = """
    DECLARE @DATABASE VARCHAR(128) = '{}';
    DECLARE @SCHEMA VARCHAR(128) = '{}';
    DECLARE @TABLE VARCHAR(128) = '{}';
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(200) = 
    'SELECT * FROM ' + CONCAT(QUOTENAME(@DATABASE), '.', QUOTENAME(@SCHEMA), '.', QUOTENAME(@TABLE)) WHERE COD = ?;
    SELECT @sql
    """.format(
    db_config.db.database, db_config.db.schema, db_config.db.table
)
con = db_config.db.connection
query = con.execute(query).fetchval()

# Now this is working
pd.read_sql_query(query, con, params=[cod_xml]).reset_index(drop=True)
```